# Application not installing on lollipop device

Tags: android, debugging, installation

I am trying to install/debug application on nexus5 with Lollipop (5.0), it is giving me following error on console window

> [2014-12-06 12:50:57 - SampleProject] Android Launch! [2014-12-06
>   12:50:57 - SampleProject] adb is running normally. [2014-12-06
>   12:50:57 - SampleProject] Performing
>   com.sampleproject.SplashScreenActivity activity launch [2014-12-06
>   12:50:57 - SampleProject] Automatic Target Mode: using device
>   '0738d9b40189c774' [2014-12-06 12:50:57 - SampleProject] Uploading
>   MovingShopV1.apk onto device '0738d9bgdcd32' [2014-12-06 12:50:58 -
>   SampleProject] Installing MovingShopV1.apk... [2014-12-06 12:51:00 -
>   SampleProject] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION
>   perm=com.sampleproject.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE pkg=com.sampleproject
>   [2014-12-06 12:51:00 - SampleProject] Please check logcat output for
>   more details. [2014-12-06 12:51:00 - SampleProject] Launch canceled!

Same application installed and debug on other device with Jelly Bean,Ice Cream Sandwich,Gingerbread

Please help....

Answer (score 4):

Starting from Lollipop it's not possible to install applications with the same permission. From the error, I think you are declaring in your manifest a permission but there is another app with the same declaration. Only one app now can declare a custom permission with that name.

Comment: I doubt that, never happen to see a custom permission! What's that?

Comment: @sud007 An app can declare a custom permission using the <permission> tag in the manifest. Other apps can declare it using <uses-permission> tag in their manifest.

Comment: Oh.. okay Nice. But for me it got solved the way I have described below. It was issue only with the apps I was developing, by some fiddling around I found that solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue as well.

While you are developing apps on a device running Lollipop. You happen to install every app, via debug to all the accounts. i.e. Main account and all guest accounts. Since Developer is a Superuser.

And when we uninstall it from one account, it remains in the other accounts unless you explicitly uninstall it from there.

So, while installing the same app from .apk manually, it says

> App with same signature already exists.

That means you have to uninstall that instance from all the users.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer should know that this is one of the solutions that I faced and got resolved by some fiddling around. So please suggest before hurting a reputation, if answer was irrelevant.